# .save() is not a Function Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I keep getting an issue that newUser.save() is not a function. This is a mongoose function that I have used before. I required mongoose correctly and am unsure of why this error is occurring. Any help is welcomed.

The error I am getting is `TypeError: newUser.save is not a function`

**My user.js inside the Models Folder**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var UserSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  email: String,
  password: String,
  info: String
});

var User = module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

module.exports.createUser = function(newUser, callback){
    bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
        bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, function(err, hash) {
            newUser.password = hash;
            newUser.save(callback);
        });
    });
}

module.exports.getUserByUsername = function(username, callback){
    User.findOne({username : username}, callback);
}

module.exports.getUserById = function(id, callback){
    User.findById(id, callback);
}

module.exports.checkPassword = function(candidatePass, hash, callback){
  bcrypt.compare(candidatePass, hash, function(err, res) {
    if(err) throw err;
    callback(null, res);
  });
}
```

**My users.js inside the Routes Folder**

```
//Mongoose Setup
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
mongoose.connect("MY_DB");
var path = require('path');
var appDir = path.dirname(require.main.filename);
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var User = require('../models/user.js');

//Express Setup
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var app = express();
var expressValidator = require("express-validator");

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(expressValidator());
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//Routes
router.get('/register', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(appDir + "/views/register.html");
})

router.post('/register', function(req, res) {
  req.check('name', 'Name must be Filled in').notEmpty();
  req.check('email', 'Email must be Filled in').notEmpty();
  req.check('email', "Invalid Email").isEmail();
  req.check('password', 'Password Field must be Filled in').notEmpty();
  req.check('password', 'Passwords do not Match').equals(req.body.password2)
  var errors = req.validationErrors();
  if(errors) res.send(errors)
  else{ User.createUser({
    name: req.body.name,
    email: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password,
    info: req.body.user_bio
  }, function(){
    console.log('User Created');
  })
}
})

//Exports
module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`createUser()` is a regular function that you're passing a regular object (as the `newUser` argument) to:

```
User.createUser({
  name : req.body.name,
  ...
}, ...);
```

Regular objects don't have a `.save` method.

What you *probably* want is to create a [static method](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#statics) as part of your model. That would allow you to call `User.createUser` like you are doing now (notice how static methods are created on the *schema*, not the *model*. Also, you have to define static methods *before* creating a model from the schema)

Comment: I was referencing https://github.com/bradtraversy/loginapp/blob/master/models/user.js while writing my code. Why would this work and mine not?

Comment: Check out [how that code is getting used](https://github.com/bradtraversy/loginapp/blob/master/routes/users.js#L41-L51). It instantiates a new user first, and passes that to `createUser`. But tbh, code-wise that project doesn't look all that great. For one, it doesn't use the tools that Mongoose provides (like the static methods that I referred to in my answer).

Answer (score 5):

You have got some things wrong here.

Something like this (User refers to your schema):

```
var user = new User();
user.name = req.body.name;
user.email = req.body.email;
user.password = req.body.password;
user.info = req.body.user_bio;
user.save().then(function(err, result) {
    console.log('User Created');
});
```

should work better. Instead of passing a new object (which obviously doesn't contain the save method), you are now creating a new object from the schema, setting the parameters, and then save it.

You then also have to change to this:

```
User.pre('save', function(next) {
    bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
        bcrypt.hash(this.password, salt, function(err, hash) {
            this.password = hash;
            next();
        });
    });
}
```

This is a hook, which is called every time before the user gets saved.

Comment: Which file would I put the hook in?

Comment: Your schema. user.js in your case. It is probably UserSchema.pre instead of User.pre by the way.

Comment: I figured out a different way to make it work, that was much simpler, thank you for trying to help. I just needed to make the newUser before calling createUser instead of doing it all at once