# Error in saving mongoose data

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

inside my users route.

```js
var User = require('../models/user');

router.route('/verify')
.get( (req, res) => {
    res.render('verify');
})
.post( (req, res, next) => {
    
        const {secretToken} = req.body;
        const user = User.findOne({'secretToken' : secretToken});
        if(!user)
        {
            req.flash('error_msg', 'No user found');
            res.redirect('/users/verify');
            return;
        }
    
        user.active = true;
        user.secretToken = '';
        user.save();
     
        
       
    
        req.flash('success_msg','Thank you.You can now login');
        res.redirect('/users/login');

        

    
    
});
```

Thats my model

```js
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username : {
        type : String,
        index : true
    },
    password : {
        type : String
    },
    email : {
        type : String,
        unique : true
    },
    password : {
        type : String
    },
    secretToken : 
    {
        type : String
    },
    active : {
        type : Boolean
    }
});

var User = module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

I set a verify route where a user will post his/her secretToken and if the secretToken match with database then that secretToken will uodated to null and my boolean element active will become true from false.So firstly i am taking the secret token from database,then i am checking it with the one which user giving,if match then i am changing my secretToken and active but problem is i cnt save it.It shows me this error.

TypeError: user.save is not a function

My problem is not in creating user,its about updating the info of already created users.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.save() is not a Function Mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37532275/save-is-not-a-function-mongoose)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
const user = User.findOne({'secretToken' : secretToken});
```

findOne returns a Mongoose promise which you are not awaiting. You probably expect to have the document when you call `user.save()`, but that's not the case. You just need to await the `findOne()` and then you should be able to call `.save()` on that document.

Comment: My node version is 6.11.2 which don't support async.

Comment: You don't need to use async/await, it is just syntatic sugar for promises. You can simply use then() to await the promise as well.

Answer (score 1):

What, I'd suggest you to do is:

```
var User = require('../models/user');

router.route('/verify')
    .get((req, res) => {
        res.render('verify');
    })
    .post((req, res, next) => {

        const {
            secretToken
        } = req.body;
        User.findOne({
            'secretToken': secretToken
        }, (user) => {
            if (!user) {
                req.flash('error_msg', 'No user found');
                res.redirect('/users/verify');
                return;
            }

            user.active = true;
            user.secretToken = '';
            user.save();
            req.flash('success_msg', 'Thank you.You can now login');
            res.redirect('/users/login');
        });
    });
```

I used a callback here, you could also use promises and then try async await functions using babel, but this works for me.